# Bootstrap 3 button group Drop UP or DOWN, base on position in table container

Tags: css, button, menu, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have problem with bootstrap drop up/down button.
Button Menu doesn't fit well on page.

I am looking for way to dynamically detect position on page of that button.
Base on location button should automatically drop up instead of drop down.

Here is problem:
on `"SHOW"` and `"Action"` button. Menu doesn't fit on page (It extends container).

https://jsfiddle.net/yz0ex8c5/

https://jsfiddle.net/3ro502q5/4/

[image]

The same happens when the button is on top. It opens `Dropping up` Instead of drop Down.

[image]

This is very important. Couse I use this buttons with drop down and drop up in table that can be **sorted**. I use [Bootstrap-table](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/) library to sort rows in table.

Comment: You could init them with javascript instead, and scope drop downs and drop ups based on the position of their table row...

Answer (score 2):

You could check the `scrollTop` position for the page, then switch between `.dropup` or `.dropdown` according to what is most suitable.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollTop = $("body").scrollTop();
    if (scrollTop<50) {
        $("#showBtnGroup").removeClass('dropdown').addClass('dropup');
    } else {    
        $("#showBtnGroup").removeClass('dropup').addClass('dropdown');        
    }        
});
```

forked fiddle -> **https://jsfiddle.net/wenz3v5r/**

Have given the btn-group an id for easy access. The evaluation value of 50 is completely arbitrary, have just added a lot of `<br>`'s to the bottom and the top of the page - that must depend on how your site looks like IRL. You should do the same (or rather the opposit) with the Action dropdown at the bottom.

Comment: I've checked. It'snt a bad solution, but is is completely unusefull for me. I have problem that menu is hidden, or to low. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/3ro502q5/4/. See post. I will update

Comment: @masterdany88 run the code in a resize event instead.? https://jsfiddle.net/oyem7rbe/

Comment: @masterdany88, did it help or should I delete the answer? If it was helpful, please upvote or accept the answer.

Comment: I can't accept Your answer cause it doesn't resolve my issue. Everything You posted works great until I sort table rows using javascript. Your's solution should recalculate button position on every data sort in table. Instead of using pop up/down menu I use grouped buttons, which isn't solution, but do the job for me. I've gave upvote for Your answer cause in some scenario may be usefull.